# I need to prove the E[aX+b], var[aX+b] given below BY using matlab

Tags: matlab

Using sample group of 10000 samples, verify the followings using simulations 
I have to show that is correct by using matlab.

1. E[aX+b] = aE[x] + b
2. var[aX+b] = a2var[X]

I find this code and by using this, I want to proof 1,2 is true

```
sum1=0;
for i=1:length(A)
  sum1=sum1+A(i);
end
M=sum1/length(A); %the mean

sum2=0;
for i=1:length(A)
    sum2=sum2+ (A(i)-M)^2;
end
V=sum2/length(A); %Varaince
```

Comment: I want to proof the gaussian distribution by using matlab.  the mean and variance. E[aX+b] = aE[x] + b, var[aX+b] = a2var[X]  is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can calculate the mean of a vector simply by `mean(A)` and you can sum a vector by using `sum(A)`, and the variance is `var(A)` or `std(A)^2`...

Remember that not all coders are familiar with notation of mathematics -- in particluar not if they are written so cryptic with no signs of *multiplication* or *power*. The expecation E() of a vector `X` is its mean (which is a scalar and therefore usually written as lower case letter) E(X):`x = mean(X)`. So what you want to proof is

```
% create random numbers
X = rand(10000,1);
a = rand(1);
b = rand(1);

% 1: E[aX+b] = aE[x] + b 
assert( mean(a*X+b) == a*mean(X)+b ,'1 failed!')

% 2: var[aX+b] = a2var[X] 
assert( var(a*X+b) == a^2*var(X) ,'2 failed!')
```

The function `assert` throws an error if its input is not true. Note that equality is a hard condition in numerical computation. It would be better to define a threshold when it can be sondered almost equal

```
TH = 1e-10;
lg = abs( mean(a*X+b) - a*mean(X)+b ) < TH
assert( lg ,'1 failed!')
```